# iosMath is crashing SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsviewcontrollerrepresentable

I'm trying to build a Mac App using SwiftUI where I want to display Math using [IosMath](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath).
I installed it using CocoaPods and I'm able to import it.
But every Time I try to get to my View Containing the MTMathUILabel my App is crashing saying : `027055+0200 latextest[1709:84867] [General] -[NSNib _initWithNibNamed:bundle:options:] could not load the nibName: latextest.Latex in bundle (null).`

My code goes as following:
In SwiftUI:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Mittel: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Das Mittel berechnet sich: ")
            Switcher()
        }
    }

}
```

calling my NSViewControllerRepresentable:

```
import AppKit
import SwiftUI


struct Switcher : NSViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeNSViewController(context: Context) -> Latex {
        print("Test")
        return Latex()
    }

    func updateNSViewController(_ nsViewController: Latex, context: Context) {
    
    }
}
```

to load the View:

```
import AppKit
import iosMath

class Latex: NSViewController {

    //public var latexstring: String! = "\\frac{2}{3}"
    //let latexlabel = MTMathUILabel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let container1 = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 70))
        let label: MTMathUILabel = MTMathUILabel()
        label.latex = "x = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}"

        label.frame = container1.frame
        container1.addSubview(label)
        self.view.addSubview(container1)
        }
}
```

Comment: Congrats on solving it yourself! You should post the solution as an answer instead of editing your question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
There was no nib file because I wasn't using InterfaceBuilder...
so I needed to change the Controller [see](https://medium.com/hyperoslo/how-to-write-an-nsviewcontroller-without-interface-builder-on-macos-760283648f12)

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

needed to be changed to.

```
override func loadView() {
self.view = NSView()
```